# Sum balance via Price + Balance From previous row

Tags: database, oracle

I have an Oracle Database 11g with Table 'Transaction' .
I want to get my balance.

I have now:

```
|   Date   |   Description    | min_plus | amount | balance |
| 4-7-2015 | Gift from Dad    | +        | 45,00  |       0 |
| 5-7-2015 | Gift to Sister   | -        | 3,00   |       0 |
| 6-7-2015 | Gift from Aunt   | +        | 2,50   |       0 |
```

I'm looking for:

```
|   Date   |   Description    | min_plus | amount | balance |
| 4-7-2015 | Gift from Dad    | +        | 45,00  |  45,00  |
| 5-7-2015 | Gift to Sister   | -        | 3,00   |  42,00  |
| 6-7-2015 | Gift from Aunt   | +        | 2,50   |  44,50  |
```

Is this possible with a virtual colmn, is it better to use PL/SQL or is this not possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a running total in plain SQL, when you select data to display. No need to create a balance column or some PL/SQL trick. Oracle windowing functions are nifty to use! In this case, we want to `SUM()` the `amount` column from the first row to the current row in the order of transaction date. You can express this in surprisingly plain language:

```
with sample_data as (
    select to_date('04-07-2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY') datecol, 'Gift from Dad' description, '+' min_plus, 45 amount from dual union all
    select to_date('05-07-2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'Gift to Sister', '-', 3 from dual union all
    select to_date('06-07-2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'Gift from Aunt', '+', 2 from dual)

select datecol, description, min_plus, amount,
sum(case when min_plus = '-' then -1 * amount else amount end) 
  over (order by datecol rows between unbounded preceding and current row) balance
from sample_data
order by datecol;
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3293)

A few notes:
The window function `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... RANGE)` does the magic. In this case we are not partitioning (restarting the calculation) the data set, so we can skip that. We are including an `ORDER BY` in the window to ensure we are summing the values in the correct order, but we are also expressing the `ORDER BY` for the entire value set as normal. And you can Google the `RANGE` clause, but as you can see it's rather plain language.

By the way, using `CHAR` for your transaction sign is awkward. I would suggest storing that as a signed integer, `1` and `-1`, so you can simply multiply the amount by the transaction sign column.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: Thanks this was what i'm looking for! Is this also possible as insert?

Comment: @mrbako If this answer helped, please feel free to make this answer as correct. For insert statements, there is a more direct way to simply `sum()` transactions to date, such as `insert into ... (select col1, col2, sum(amount) from ...)`. However, I don't see the need to store the balance in your transaction row. What if you have a backdated transaction? All subsequent rows would be incorrect in that case. I would keep the total account balance in a separate table, and then show your running total as part of the display using SQL such as this.

Comment: A last question. Is it also possible to sum up a start balance on the first record eg. 100 so my balance on row 1 will be 145?